# How to prevent redirect from login.microsoftonline.com to login.live.com while using new outlook rest api's

Tags: outlook, adal, outlook-restapi, azure-active-directory

Using the new outlook rest api's to import contacts from outlook/hotmail email accounts. There is a minor glitch though, once the user clicks the import contacts button and the initial MS auth dialog pops up (url - login.microsoftonline.com), as soon as the user finishes entering their email address, the page suddenly redirects to login.live.com.

This is bad because:

1. this happens without any warning (user could be in middle of entering their password for example)
2. what's the point of using the new api's if the auth is still being handled by the old live connect api endpoint.

Would like to know if there is anyway to prevent this redirect from happening?
Maybe I am missing some param which needs to passed in to the initial auth url?